# How can I deal with scrolling event in Apple terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, xterm

I want to make a console app, and it need to receive key input from console

I found it works well in alternate screen, but has a question.
[image: Apple Terminal]

When I scroll in Apple Terminal, the code cannot catch the scrolling operation but printing `^[OA` on terminal. 
This will not occur in iTerm.app

And this will also not occur when using `less` or `vim` in Terminal.app

I hope to get a way that I can read the scrolling operation and do not show the `^[OA`

Here is my example code by Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'io/console'

def rc
  STDIN.echo = false
  STDIN.raw!

  input = STDIN.getc.chr
  if input == "\e" then
    input << STDIN.read_nonblock(3) rescue nil
    input << STDIN.read_nonblock(2) rescue nil
  end
ensure
  STDIN.echo = true
  STDIN.cooked!

  return input
  STDIN.getch
end


print "\e[?1049h"
print "\e[?1h"
print "\e="
print "\e[1;24r"

loop do
  c = rc
  break if c == "\u0003"
  p c
  print c
end

print "\e[?1049l"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a terminal-specific feature.  I don't see a relevant setting in the *Preferences* dialog for Terminal.app

You might be able to accomplish this with an add-on (as people used to recommend when asked how to get Terminal.app to pass mouse-events to an application).

For background: Terminal.app has (slowly) added features for compatibility with xterm.  This was not a feature originally in xterm.  iTerm2 got it by copying either/or gnome-terminal or xterm (it's hard to say since except for xterm, no one bothers to document when features were added).

If either iTerm2 or Terminal.app had copied the feature from xterm, for instance, those would make the feature *optional* as done by xterm in [patch #282](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282) (but note followup work to complete the feature).  xterm provides both an X resource setting, and a control sequence (private mode 1007) for configuring it.  In contrast, VTE's behavior (the library supplying all of the functionality to the gnome-terminal "skin") is hard-coded.

I've commented on the feature here:

- [Disable scroll inside Xfce terminal / Avoid scrolling through command history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278677/disable-scroll-inside-xfce-terminal-avoid-scrolling-through-command-history/278756#278756)
- [tmux mouse scrolling without altering copy/paste?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312261/tmux-mouse-scrolling-without-altering-copy-paste/312269#312269)